# Using attr to set css variable inline that work with CSP

Tags: css, content-security-policy, css-variables

I was thinking how I can use css variables without using inline styles. I thought that I can use this:

```css
[data-color] {
    --color: attr(data-color color, green);
}
* {
    color: var(--color, blue);
}
```

```html
<div data-color="red">hello</div>
```

It seems that attr work only in pseudo selectors (and probably only on `content:` property), but [MDN attr page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) says:

> The attr() CSS function is used to retrieve the value of an attribute of the selected element and use it in the stylesheet. It can also be used on pseudo-elements, in which case the value of the attribute on the pseudo-element's originating element is returned.

There is even demo but it don't work in Chrome on Linux, so it's of no use to me. It even don't work in Firefox on Linux.

Is there any other way to use css variables without inline styles and without writing dynamic  `<style></style>` and nonce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet. In the same link you can read:

> Note: The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but support for properties other than content is experimental, and support for the type-or-unit parameter is sparse.

Still no browser support the `attr()` for properties different than content and also no support for the type-or-unit.

Worth to note that you can use `attr()` inside a CSS variable but it need to be later used with content. CSS variables is only an intermediate so we don't evaluate the support based on the variable but based on the property that will use the variable.

```css
[data-color] {
  --color: attr(data-color);
}

*::before {
  content: var(--color, "default");
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div data-color="red">hello</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's probably just `content: var(attr(data-color), "default");` the attr is not expanded inside `--color: `and used directly as string in content  inside var.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting use of the CSS attr property, but as the question states, the support for it outside of the pseudo element property is sparse see for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr

It's actually slightly worse than that because if you have:

```css
* {
    color: var(--color, blue);
}
[data-color] {
    --color: green;
    --color: attr(data-color);
}
```

```html
<div data-color="red">hello</div>
```

similar to in the question but separated out to be more explicit. The `--color: attr(data-color)` does not flag a warning and get ignored and the green used. Instead it is accepted and --color set to the string. It's as if the browser sort of recognises the attr and that it should do something with it but doesn't actually do it fully.

Answer (score -1):

For everyone who still want to manage CSS variable on HTML you can do it like that:

```css
* {
    color: var(--color, blue);
}
```

```html
<div style="--color: red">hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
```

Comment: did you read the question? `Is there any other way to use css variables without inline styles and without writing dynamic <style></style> and nonce?` I need this because CSP which needs to validate each CSS.

Comment: My bad, didn't saw that part

Comment: The clue is in the title `that work with CSP` inline style required to generate nonce to be valid, I wanted to avoid it.

Comment: Sorry :/ I create a question because I wanted to handle CSS var from HTML, and my question was deleted because similar to yours (even if I already read it and did not found what I was looking for). And after that I found this trick... So I wanted to share it with everyone (if someone need it in the future). Sorry if it's not working for your case :/

Comment: Oh, too bad. Was it deleted or closed? Because yous should edit the question to be more clear that this is not the answer to your question. I happen to me sometimes and I need to clarify why my question is different.

Comment: what is this answer?